# Aproach for a cognitive map with Leaflet / direct pixel->point ratio at maximal zoom

Tags: javascript, php, leaflet

I am trying to use Leaflet to realize a cognitive map program as my cs50x final project (so I am no expert).

It should use the marker/windows features for the text-entries and streets/polylines for the links. Because it should be able to handle big amounts of data, the database should be indexed in local cells so only necessary entries will be searched and shown.
To archive this the best way would be a 1:1 pixel to point ratio at maximum zoom, but even after two days of trying and searching I haven't found a proper way to do it.

I have already searched the game map and non-geographic imagery solutions but it seems they all start from a fixed big image/fixed borders.

Comment: I'm pretty familiar with Leaflet and GIS, but I really don't have any idea what you're asking. Are you able to elaborate? What do you mean by "pixel to point ratio"? What do you mean "cognitive map program"? "Only necessary entries will be searched and shown"?

Comment: Cognitive maps are a learning/writing technique were you use graphical links like arrows to show the relation between and within topics. "necessary entries" means that only the markers in the visible area were loaded or with high priority if zoomed out. "pixel to point ratio" means that on maximum zoom one point in the coordinate system equals one pixel.